# In Entity framework load child in parent entity (non primary key association)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, edmx

I am very new to Entity Framework and so I don't know the technical terms use in it. I am sorry for my bad English.

I am working in a project which has entity framework in it and has an `.edmx` file. The file has entities created in it.

So I created 2 entities and named it TableA and TableB. 
pid is entity key of TableA and cid is entity key of TableB .
And created many to one relationship in it.
i.e. TableA row1 can have TableB_cid=1
TableA row2 can also have TableB_cid=2

And then I did "Generate database from model"

```
CREATE TABLE [TableA] (
    [pid] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [TableB_cid] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
GO


CREATE TABLE [TableB] (
    [cid] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);

pid|name|TableB_cid
--------------------
1 | a | 2
2 | b | 2
3 | c | 1


cid|name
------------
1 | s
2 | f
```

Now in the C# code i wrote this,

```
TableA obj = repository.All().Single(w=>w.pid == "1")
context.Entry<TableA>(obj).Reference<TableB>(o => o.TableB).Load();
```

Now this will load the TableB whose cid=1 (but what i actually wanted was to load TableB whose cid=2).

I think its matching primary key to primary key and not TableB_cid (TableA) to cid (TableB).

So what i am doing wrong please help.

**Edit:**
In short I am looking for a way where I can add association of a Non Primary column of table A with a Primary column of table B in Entity Framework 4.0.
And I don't want to use linq queries and joins. I have tried but I cant a find a way or option in edmx file where i can do it.
[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks,

M

Comment: Is `repository` your `DbContext` or a custom service layer repository?  What does `repository.All()` return?

Comment: Hi AJ. repository is custom service and uses unit of work, and `repository.All()` returns `IQueryable<Parent>`

Comment: Are you sure Child_Cid should be in the Parents table? If a parent can have many children, then the Children table should have [Parent_Pid], right?

Comment: Hi franklins, I think i had used wrong naming conventions so now i have edited the question.

Comment: Everything looks good now, correct?

Comment: yes I am shocked to see that this is working now... few hours ago i was getting some other values. But in two other entities i did the same association and there its not working. What should i look for according to u?

Comment: You should post the relevant information in a new question, since this one has been answered and you are probably having a different issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but in your example, are you simply attempting to access the TableB entity of the TableA with Id 1?

If so, how about this:

```
TableA obj = repository.All().Single(w=>w.pid == "1");
TableB SecondTable = obj.TableB;
```

SecondTable.cid should be 2, is and obj.pid should be 1.  If not, what values are you getting?

Comment: Hi mark, I have attached the snaphot. And I am trying to load the child but the wrong child is getting loaded. I mean its taking TableA's primary key and not the TableB_cid.

Comment: I've updated my post according to your new setup - does this help?

Comment: I am getting `obj.TableB=null` I think its due to lazy loading. What should I do to load it?

Comment: To load the navigation property: obj.TableB.Load(); However - I'm curious as to what the FK is - is obj.TableB_cid == 2 ?

Comment: I have attached another snap, and i cant check what `obj.TableB_cid` is as its not a public property of obj.

Comment: In your snapshot, in the Add Association box, you can check the box to add the foreign key property to TableA - can you do this until we can isolate what's going on?  If you need to turn it off for business logic reasons, you can once the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var childs = from c in context.Children
                      where c.cid = o.Child_cid;
```

I think that should help you.

Comment: but I cant use the linq query due to some reasons. I think I am missing some setting when I created the entity in edmx. ANd i dont know what.

Comment: Do you have added the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: hi andre please see my edit. I dont want to use linq queries as it doesnt fits in my project architecture.

Comment: Maybe following link will help you. 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Hi andre I went to the link and applied the same logic, but it returns the same wrong result.